# Casting a packet to get a IP header

Tags: c, networking, ip

I need to iterate over the IP header.

I have the following piece of code to decompose a packet.

```
#define SIZE_ETHERNET 14;
ethernet = (struct ether_header*) packet; 
ip = (struct ip*) (packet + SIZE_ETHERNET);
```

According to the IP struct given by `<netinet/ip.h>`, I have found that the size of the IP header was given by `size_ip = IP_HL(ip)*4`

But I don't understand why we need to multiply `IP_HL(ip)` by 4 to get it.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm editing this right now.

Answer (score 0):

The header length field of the IP header is the number of DWORDS (32 bits) in the header.  The `size_ip` value here is the number bytes (8 bits) in the header.  So to get the value of `size_ip` from the header length field, the conversion is `*4` to account for the number of bytes in a DWORD.